# Setting unix_socket in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I'm testing out Lumen, and I've set up my database connection via the .env file. In Laravel, I need to set the  unix_socket parameter locally, which I do in the database config. Unfortunately Lumen seems to only config the database via the .env file. Is there a way to set the unix_socket parameter in the .env file?

Or is there an alternate way of doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around this issue that works for me is to change the DB_HOST in your .env file from

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

to

```
DB_HOST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

... where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is replaced with your local MySQL server IP address (e.g. 127.0.0.1) thereby eliminating the need for the unix_socket.

Comment: To the downvoters: Please leave a comment at least as to why you're downvoting. Thank you.

Comment: This is not using the socket, though... This is just connecting over TCP locally.

Comment: Two years later, but the op said, "Or is there an alternate way of doing it?" ... so, this is an alternate way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to set the config value manually. For example in `bootstrap/app.php` like this:

```
$app['config']->set('database.connections.mysql.unix_socket', 'asdf');
```

Or you can do the same in a Service Provider, it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately this didn't work, but you pointed me in the right direction. You can create your own config files (e.g. app/config/database.php) which overwrites the defaults, so I've done that.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that. My solution probably doesn't work because it's too late at that time to set the value... I'll update the answer later or feel free to add an answer of your own if you'd like :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DB_HOST=localhost;unix_socket=/cloudsql/cloud-project-name:us-east1:sql-instance-name
```

[Source](https://shocksolution.com/2018/05/14/configuring-laravel-lumen-applications-to-connect-to-sql-database-sockets/)